# Polars dataframe: create new columns while pivot dataframe based on value in a column

Tags: dataframe, python-polars

Say, I have a polars dataframe as below:

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
 {
     "date": ["d1", "d1", "d1", "d1", "d1", "d1"],
     "ticker": ["t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1"],
     "positionType": ["Long", "Long", "Short", "Short", "Long", "Short"],
     "predictionType": ["p1", "s1", "p1", "s1", "p1", "p1"],
     "holdingBars": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
     "res": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 }
)
```

| date | ticker | positionType | predictionType | holdingBars | res |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | d1 | t1 | Long | p1 | 1 |
| 1 | d1 | t1 | Long | s1 | 1 |
| 2 | d1 | t1 | Short | p1 | 1 |
| 3 | d1 | t1 | Short | s1 | 1 |
| 4 | d1 | t1 | Long | p1 | 2 |
| 5 | d1 | t1 | Short | p1 | 2 |

I have tried pivoting it as below:

```
df.pivot(
 values="res", index=["date", "ticker", "predictionType"], columns=["positionType", "holdingBars"], aggregate_function="first")
```

Output:

| date | ticker | predictionType | Long | Short | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| d1 | t1 | p1 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 5 |
| d1 | t1 | s1 | 2 | 4 | 2 | null |

1. I would, however, like to see it as below. basically, a concatenation of positionType and holdingBars columns and the corresponding res value

| date | ticker | predictionType | Long_1 | Short_1 | Long_2 | Short_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| d1 | t1 | p1 | 1 | 3 | 5 | 6 |
| d1 | t1 | s1 | 2 | 4 | null | null |

2. I would, also like to add additional columns: Long_1/Short_1 and Long_2/Short_2

| date | ticker | predictionType | Long_1 | Short_1 | Long_2 | Short_2 | Long_1 / Short_1 | Long_2 / Short_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| d1 | t1 | p1 | 1 | 3 | 5 | 6 | 0.3 | 0.83 |
| d1 | t1 | s1 | 2 | 4 | null | null | 0.5 | NaN |

Please note that this is a subset of data, it can have multiple tickers across multiple dates and res can be across multiple holding periods.

Any idea how an achieve these, please?

ta!

Comment: Taking `Long_2` for example, why is it `[3, 4]`? Should that not be `Short_1`?

Comment: Sorry, I must have messed up the output in the tables. The output should be from rows pertaining to position type and holding bars. I will definitely fix this when I am back home

Comment: No worries, just making sure I was understanding things. It looks like you just want to add the column name before pivoting e.g. `df.with_columns(columns = pl.col("positionType") + "_" + pl.col("holdingBars").cast(str)).pivot(..., columns="columns"`

Comment: Ahh ok, I will try this out and post the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the column name before pivoting:

```
(
    df.with_columns(
        columns=pl.col('positionType') + '_' + pl.col('holdingBars').cast(str)
    ).pivot(
        values='res',
        index=['date', 'ticker', 'predictionType'],
        columns='columns',
        aggregate_function='first',
    )
)
```

```
shape: (2, 7)
┌──────┬────────┬────────────────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────────┐
│ date ┆ ticker ┆ predictionType ┆ Long_1 ┆ Short_1 ┆ Long_2 ┆ Short_2 │
│ ---  ┆ ---    ┆ ---            ┆ ---    ┆ ---     ┆ ---    ┆ ---     │
│ str  ┆ str    ┆ str            ┆ i64    ┆ i64     ┆ i64    ┆ i64     │
╞══════╪════════╪════════════════╪════════╪═════════╪════════╪═════════╡
│ d1   ┆ t1     ┆ p1             ┆ 1      ┆ 3       ┆ 5      ┆ 6       │
│ d1   ┆ t1     ┆ s1             ┆ 2      ┆ 4       ┆ null   ┆ null    │
└──────┴────────┴────────────────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────────┘
```

#### Long_1/Short_1

As your Long/Short items are pairs, and in order - you could groupby and use first/last to isolate them:

```
(
   df.with_columns(
      (pl.col('positionType') == 'Long').cumsum().over('ticker', 'predictionType')
         .alias('predId')
   )
   .groupby('date', 'ticker', 'predictionType', 'predId', maintain_order=True)
   .agg(
      pl.first('res').alias('Long'),
      pl.last('res').alias('Short'),
      (pl.first('res') / pl.last('res')).alias('Long/Short'),
   )
)
```

```
shape: (3, 7)
┌──────┬────────┬────────────────┬────────┬──────┬───────┬────────────┐
│ date ┆ ticker ┆ predictionType ┆ predId ┆ Long ┆ Short ┆ Long/Short │
│ ---  ┆ ---    ┆ ---            ┆ ---    ┆ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---        │
│ str  ┆ str    ┆ str            ┆ u32    ┆ i64  ┆ i64   ┆ f64        │
╞══════╪════════╪════════════════╪════════╪══════╪═══════╪════════════╡
│ d1   ┆ t1     ┆ p1             ┆ 1      ┆ 1    ┆ 3     ┆ 0.333333   │
│ d1   ┆ t1     ┆ s1             ┆ 1      ┆ 2    ┆ 4     ┆ 0.5        │
│ d1   ┆ t1     ┆ p1             ┆ 2      ┆ 5    ┆ 6     ┆ 0.833333   │
└──────┴────────┴────────────────┴────────┴──────┴───────┴────────────┘
```

You can then `.melt()` the `['date', 'ticker', 'predictionType', 'predId']` columns and pivot.

```
(
   df.with_columns(
      (pl.col('positionType') == 'Long').cumsum().over('ticker', 'predictionType')
         .alias('predId')
   )
   .groupby('date', 'ticker', 'predictionType', 'predId', maintain_order=True)
   .agg(
      pl.first('res').alias('Long'),
      pl.last('res').alias('Short'),
      (pl.first('res') / pl.last('res')).alias('Long/Short')
   )
   .melt(
      id_vars = ['date', 'ticker', 'predictionType', 'predId'],
      variable_name = 'column'
   )
   .with_columns(
      pl.col('column') + '_' + pl.col('predId').cast(str)
   ).pivot(
      values = 'value',
      index = ['date', 'ticker', 'predictionType'],
      columns = 'column',
      aggregate_function = None
   )
)
```

```
shape: (2, 9)
┌──────┬────────┬────────────────┬────────┬────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┐
│ date ┆ ticker ┆ predictionType ┆ Long_1 ┆ Long_2 ┆ Short_1 ┆ Short_2 ┆ Long/Short_1 ┆ Long/Short_2 │
│ ---  ┆ ---    ┆ ---            ┆ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---          ┆ ---          │
│ str  ┆ str    ┆ str            ┆ f64    ┆ f64    ┆ f64     ┆ f64     ┆ f64          ┆ f64          │
╞══════╪════════╪════════════════╪════════╪════════╪═════════╪═════════╪══════════════╪══════════════╡
│ d1   ┆ t1     ┆ p1             ┆ 1.0    ┆ 5.0    ┆ 3.0     ┆ 6.0     ┆ 0.333333     ┆ 0.833333     │
│ d1   ┆ t1     ┆ s1             ┆ 2.0    ┆ null   ┆ 4.0     ┆ null    ┆ 0.5          ┆ null         │
└──────┴────────┴────────────────┴────────┴────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┘
```

The use of `.melt` causes the upcasting to floats which may or may not be an issue.

It's also possible to "pivot" in the following manner:

```
pivots = 'Long', 'Short', 'Long/Short'

(
   df.with_columns(
      (pl.col('positionType') == 'Long').cumsum().over('ticker', 'predictionType')
         .alias('predId')
   )
   .groupby('date', 'ticker', 'predictionType', 'predId', maintain_order=True)
   .agg(
      pl.first('res').alias('Long'),
      pl.last('res').alias('Short'),
      (pl.first('res') / pl.last('res')).alias('Long/Short')
   )
   .groupby('date', 'ticker', 'predictionType')
   .agg(pivots)
   .with_columns(
      pl.col(col).list.to_struct(
         n_field_strategy = 'max_width',
         fields = lambda idx, col=col: f'{col}_{idx + 1}'
      )
      for col in pivots
   )
   .unnest(pivots)
)
```

```
shape: (2, 9)
┌──────┬────────┬────────────────┬────────┬────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┐
│ date ┆ ticker ┆ predictionType ┆ Long_1 ┆ Long_2 ┆ Short_1 ┆ Short_2 ┆ Long/Short_1 ┆ Long/Short_2 │
│ ---  ┆ ---    ┆ ---            ┆ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---          ┆ ---          │
│ str  ┆ str    ┆ str            ┆ i64    ┆ i64    ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ f64          ┆ f64          │
╞══════╪════════╪════════════════╪════════╪════════╪═════════╪═════════╪══════════════╪══════════════╡
│ d1   ┆ t1     ┆ s1             ┆ 2      ┆ null   ┆ 4       ┆ null    ┆ 0.5          ┆ null         │
│ d1   ┆ t1     ┆ p1             ┆ 1      ┆ 5      ┆ 3       ┆ 6       ┆ 0.333333     ┆ 0.833333     │
└──────┴────────┴────────────────┴────────┴────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┘
```

Comment: thanks mate! this works like a charm! can you also pls help with:

I would, also like to add additional columns: Long_1/Short_1 and Long_2/Short_2

Comment: Can you add an example with the expected output?

Comment: sure, of course, I have updated the question with example output - ta!

Comment: Is there always a Long/Short pairing in the data for each ticker/predictionType? (and they're ordered by date?)

Comment: yes and yes. there is always a long and short pairing, one of them could be null, and I always keep them sorted

Comment: You can loop through the columns generated by the pivot, I've added an example. It feels like there should be a nicer way to do this without using pivot.

Comment: ahh, I have been trying out with groupby and then pivot etc. this works for now. I will keep playing around post back if I can find another solution. thanks for your time on this mate, ta!

Comment: Yeah, it feels like this should be simpler to do. I've added another possible approach, but it seems a bit verbose - perhaps I'm missing something more obvious here.

Comment: Ta! I will try these out

Comment: thanks mate! this did work. I am playing around with polars, I will post back with another solution, if I find any. ta!

Comment: Yeah looking at it again, perhaps `.pivot` is the nicer solution. Instead of using `.pipe` to process the result of the pivot - I've added an approach to setting up all the data first pre-pivot. It seems simpler?

Comment: nice, this seems pretty clever - ta for all your time on this!